# Core Data versioning programmatically

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, core-data-migration

I'm aware and I know how to do the versioning of core data through Interface Builder.
The thing is, I want (have, in fact) to do this only by code, since the creation of the schema and the versioning per se.
Is it possible or am I'm going in the wrong way?

Comment: You mean as in, create a whole new version of the data model in code?

Comment: Yeah, but I want to maintain the data stored on the previous database. Any hint?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is perfectly possible to create, explore and alter managed object models in code. Check out these documentation resources:

[NSManagedObjectModel](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectModel_Class/index.html), having an `entities` property which you can populate with [NSEntityDescription](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSEntityDescription_Class/index.html) objects etc.

Comment: So, which part of my answer in view of data migration did you not understand? With the linked APIs you can create a new version, alter the data model, and initiate lightweight or custom migration. Duh.

Comment: This is not very helpful in terms of how to do a custom migration in code. It's fairly easy to setup a data model in code. But to do a migration in code is less discussed. Not to say you don't mention objects that are more relevant to migration like coding a NSMappingModel.